# Turbulenz Game Engine : Missing manage.py from SDK Version 0.28.0 for windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, turbulenz

Github repo got manage.py file but not sdk. What to use for SDK to run commands?

After installing the SDK there is no file called manage.py to run commands like `python manage.py apps multiworm` in VirtualEnv. How to compile new game?

How to fix manage.py missing file problem?

Got python 2.7.
Turbulenz SDK Versions 0.28.0 on windows 8.1

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend using the SDK. It basically pre-dates the entire project becoming open-source and is a stripped down set of the things you will find in the github repo.

Personally I use commands similar to `makehtml --mode canvas-debug -t . libs/all_my_stuff.js -o debug.html` to build a project, then I run the project with `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` but your mileage may vary.